# MySql query contains a string in field

Tags: mysql, sql

The question may be asked several times and I checked all of them but I can't get the answer.
I have a field named variables in my database 'test'.I have worked the query

```
select 'variables' from test WHERE variables LIKE '%{$ifIndex}%';
```

variables field contains comma seperated strings like `ifIndex, IfType, IfStatus`
but I can't get it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select variables from test WHERE 'ifIndex' LIKE CONCAT('%',`variables` , '%') ;
```

if you're trying to match just the start:

```
select variables from test WHERE 'ifIndex' LIKE CONCAT(`variables` , '%')
```

Comment: What about if the field contains space. can i replace it when querying?

Comment: what do you mean by field?  like the field name?  or the value in the field being searched?   If its the field name, you should dhave no problem.  Otherwise, you need to take into account regular expressions..  see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: i mean sometimes the 'variable' in the table contains '  ifIndex'

Answer (score 5):

This will achieve the results you want when you put the string you are looking for using just the % for the wildcard on either side.

```
select variables from test WHERE variables LIKE '%ifIndex%';
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code

```
select variables from test
WHERE variables LIKE '%{$ifIndex}%';
```

For field names don't put the single quotaition.